# paypal api Determine the price of the product using php

Tags: php, api

I have 3 packages on my site, one price is $ 20, the second price is $ 40, and the third price is $ 70. I want to link it to paypa api. When the user clicks, for example, on the package whose price is $ 20, 20 dollars are added to my account, no more, no less

Comment: show us what you have done (share your codes).

Comment: Do you have a shopping cart on your website or is each product directly linked to paypal / must do so?

Answer (score 1):

*Explanation / Example:*

Let's say you click on the `a` tag of product 1 ($20):

```
<a href="buy_product_1.php">Buy product 1 ($20)</a>
```

This opens the `buy_product_1.php` file. Inside that file are all information about product 1 and it will redirect you directly to paypal.

**buy_product_1.php**

```
<?php

$sandbox = false;
$paypal_url = $sandbox ? "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" : "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

$data = array(
    'cmd'           => '_xclick',
    'business'      => 'your_paypal_business_email',
    'cancel_return' => 'your_cancel_url',
    'notify_url'    => 'your_ipn_url',
    'currency_code' => 'USD',
    'return'        => 'your_return_url',
    'item_number'   => '1',
    'item_name'     => 'Product 1',
    'quantity'      => '1',
    'amount'        => '20.00',
    'image_url'     => 'your_business_logo_img_url'
);

header("location:" . $paypal_url . "?" . http_build_query($data));
exit();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for help me❤❤❤matja

Comment: I'm glad i could help.

Comment: How can i learn an api and i also have another question how do i understand paypal api quickly? Because when I asked the question, I found a quick response from you, how could you do that

Comment: To learn & understand the paypal api read here: [PayPal Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/)